# Good morning vs. Good night

Tags: word-usage, greetings

I find that *good morning* is used both at the beginning of conversations (as in, "Good morning! How are you today?") and as a means of saying farewell.  The same is true for *good evening.* In contrast, you never hear people greeting each other with *good night* then launching into conversation.  It's always used as a greeting on its own ( as when passing someone by in the street) or as a farewell remark.  I don't know if this is regional or not (I'm from Pennsylvania), but it seems quite arbitrary.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @tchrist you are right; it's definitely a duplicate.  My mistake.

Comment: It's a duplicate for sure but the answers provided aren't particularly satisfying.

Comment: I'd be most interested in knowing whether this distinction is universal or not. Is it true in the UK as well?